# Removing duplicate features in PyQGIS

Tags: python, qgis

I'm trying to remove duplicate features from PyQGIS. Manually I can do it by using "Edit -> Merge Selected Features" and then "Multipart to Singlepart" from fTools in QGIS, but can this functionality be reached from PyQGIS? Can't find anything about Merge in the API docs.

I tried using QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve but it seems to keep the duplicate parts in the multipart features created. I hope someone can describe an easy way to accomplish what I'm after.

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 3):

MMQGIS plugin contains a tool to remove duplicate geometries. You can either use that or build upon its source code.